# Why does Logic App HTTP request fail when response has unknown character

Tags: .net, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which is making a HTTP GET request to an API. HTTP is failing with the following error.

> BadRequest. Http request failed as the content was not valid: 'Unable to translate bytes [9B] at index 790 from specified code page to Unicode.'

I am able to invoke the same API using Postman without an any error, however, I can see in the response that there are some unknown characters.

Does anyone know how I can work around this issue using Azure Logic Apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by the coding of the response from your api, postman will parse the response automatically but HTTP action in logic app will not do it. As I don't know the coding of your data, so just provide some suggestions for your reference.

**1.** Please check if the response data is in UTF-8. If not, you can use code like below to convert the response data in your api.

```
UTF8.decode(response.bodyBytes)
```

**2.** Add a field `Accept` in your HTTP action headers.

```
Accept: text/html;charset=US-ASCII, text/html;charset=UTF-8, text/plain;
charset=US-ASCII,text/plain;charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Try first: Accept: */*